# Add values to listbox from dataset - NullReferenceException error (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to populate a single record from a `dataset` into a `listbox`. I can see that the dataset is populated with the expected value with the column header "PLI" in the dataset visualizer. I've tried to use the following command to populate the listbox with the value in the dataset:

```
lstExistingPLI.Items.Add(New ListItem(ds.Tables("PLI").ToString()))
```

I keep getting an unhandled NullReferenceException error. I've also tried using

```
lstExistingPLI.Items.Add(ds.Tables("PLI").ToString())
```

and getting the same error. Can anyone help me out with what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You should post your code + full error - also 'New' should be 'new'.

Comment: `ds.Tables` returns a `DataTable`. Why do you think that `DataTable.ToString` returns anything that could be added to a ListBox in a useful way? Do you want to add the fields of every DataRow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i must admit that i don't know what causes your `NullRefernceException`.

Your ListBox `lstExistingPLI` might be null if you haven't [initialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973814.aspx) it. The `DataSet` ds might be null if it was not initialized. Maybe you have initialized it but you haven't added a DataTable with name "PLI" to it, then null would be returned from the [`DataTableCollection.Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58st33fb.aspx) property.

However, `ds.Tables` returns a `DataTable`. Why do you think that `DataTable.ToString` returns anything that could be added to a ListBox in a useful way? Do you want to add the fields of every DataRow?

(assuming that all is [initialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973814.aspx) correctly)

```
For Each  row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
    'assuming that PLI is not the table but the field that you want to add to the ListBox'
    lstExistingPLI.Items.Add(New ListItem(row.Field(Of String)("PLI")))
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. The snippet you gave me results in an error: "Expression is of type 'System.Data.DataTable', which is not collection type.

Comment: Sorry, haven't used the DataTable's `Rows` property, edited my answer accordingly(`ds.Tables(0).Rows`).